# How do you adjust a duct vent to get better suction flow from the fireplace?

Tags: vent, fireplace, woodstove

I have 2 vents similar to this one on my wood-burning stove, but there's not much information on how to adjust the pipe in order to get a proper ventilation seal. Does anyone have any advice on how to get it to seal properly?

[image]

Comment: A picture of your wood stove/fireplace showing the vents would be more helpful.  The picture you have, is just a common elbow pipe.  Sealing those elbows comes to just screws or maybe duct tape if wanting a good seal.

Comment: it sits outside of the wall on its legs